# Magento 2 filtering product collection and sorting

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, collection, product-collection, product-sorting

Considering below I can display products with true value of my custom attribute in ascending order based on position. How can I have products with false right after these in ascending too?

```
if ($subject->getCurrentOrder() == 'CustomAttribute') {
            $collection ->addAttributeToFilter('myCustomAtt',1)->setOrder('position', 'asc');
            $collection->load();
        }
```

Is there any way to append `$collection ->addAttributeToFilter('myCustomAtt',0)->setOrder('position', 'asc');` at the end of the `$collection`?

Comment: i don't get you want to double sort the collection based on position and your custom attribute value?

Comment: it's like displaying all products with true value then all with fasle on my custom attribute, in ascending.

Comment: I added the answer hope it will helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort it by give values

```
if ($subject->getCurrentOrder() == 'CustomAttribute') {
     $values=array(1);
                $collection->setOrder('position', 'asc');
$collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(myCustomAtt,' . implode(',', $values).')'));
                $collection->load();
            }
```

[Check](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-sort-collection-given-ids/) for detail

Comment: after more testing, I realized it does not list all products, it just displays  neq' => '1' collection :(

Comment: @Zinat just remove the filter part. update the code check it

Comment: now I have exactly your code, but I don't get getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(myCustomAtt,' . implode(',', $values).')')); at the end of the collection

Comment: @Zinat you want to sort the current attribute value first. this is code doing

Comment: let's forget $collection->setOrder('position', 'asc') for now ... First we display collection that has myCustomAtt as true and then collection that has myCustomAtt as false ... and thanks for following up

Comment: @Zinat you want two separate collection or one single collection?

Comment: I want single collection with situation I explained , First we display products that has myCustomAtt as true and then products that has myCustomAtt as false ... BTW, I got this with latest Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'myCustomAtt' in 'order clause'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74146/discussion-between-zinat-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use sorting instead of filtering.

The following code will sort by myCustomAtt first, then by position.

```
if ($subject->getCurrentOrder() == 'CustomAttribute') {    $collection->addAttributeToSort('myCustomAtt','DESC')->addAttributeToSort('position','ASC');
    $collection->load();
}
```

Comment: Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Select_Exception): You cannot define a correlation name 'myCustomAtt_t' more than once, what does it mean?

Comment: You cannot use addAttributeToSort on 'myCustomAtt' twice

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you.

```
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('myCustomAtt', array('eq' => array(1,0)))->setOrder('position', 'asc');
    $collection->load();
```